# How to handle sticky-sessions with Socket.io 1.0 when behind a firewall?

Tags: node.js, session, nginx, cluster-computing, socket.io-1.0

I am trying to setup a POC for myself using Nginx, Node.js and Socket.io 1.0 using clustering on Rackspace.  I am under the assumption that I need to use clustering because I want this to be scalable across multiple servers if needed. I want each node to have their own instance and as of now I can't see any need for each of the instances to have to talk to each other for any reason.  Again as of now, I believe I need to use clustering for simply the fact that I may have many clients connecting to this server and I want it to be able to grown and shrink accordingly. My end goal is to build a little POC similar to what is shown here: https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/real-time-gaming-with-node-js-websocket-on-gcp

I just got what I believe to be a valid setup of the new Socket.io 1.0 established, but when connecting from different devices behind my router, they are all showing the same PID in my logging and I assume this is due to the required sticky-sessioning by Socket.io.  I am not sure if this is the same as the worker-process that we used to get with clustering, but again I am still trying to get my head wrapped around all this.

First I want to know if using clustering and sticky-sessions is required, since only 1 PID is issued for the same external IP, is there anyway to have each computer treated as its own instance?  I do not want to send back a response that updates everyone behind that IP.

My second question is this and it may be a stupid question but i'm asking anyway :) In reading about how to get the sticky-sessions working I kept seeing people stating to "use sticky-sessions, like by IP Address".  The word "like" is what got me.  I seemed to have found people referring to using sticky-sessions with IP and cookies. Can you do it by anything else, such as a username, issued token or anything? My concern is if someone is playing with this on a mobile device and they switch towers, the tower will issue a new IP so in-turn a new PID would get issued and essentially that players game lost.  Am I understanding this right?

Please forgive me as I am new to Node.js but thought this would be a cool way to learn node.js and clustering in the cloud.  Any info or direction that anyone can provide would be of great help.  Many of the tuts all seem to broadcast events to everyone but i am looking for a scalable solution where each connection can be sent events individually most fo the time. I also need to solve for a number of people behind the same firewall being treated as separate connections when the server communicates to them.  Again if there is any reading or tutorials that you feel may help me with socket.io 1.0 and what I am trying to do, please reply.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general since you are using `websockets` you don't need to worry about stickiness as long as the connection does not terminate. This communication is bi-directional and the http connection is kept alive. If the connection drops the client is essentially reconnecting and starting over. So yes if anyone's ip gets renewed you will now get a new server socket.

Refer to article [using-multiple-nodes](http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/) where it states the requirement for XHR/JSONP long polling clients.

I don;t believe nginx has capabilities of load balancing on things like MAC address etc as per [nginx load-balancing](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html) techniques.

I am thinking that you may need a solid load balancer that can use MAC addresses, virtual port ID or some headers for routing.